# Why are query results in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1bk-Yp83zd6vnTrvZnVaGKHDuCJNTiOwEGEw5GDwHrOg";"Покупатели!B2:O")};"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col6,Col,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14 WHERE Col3 = 'Потенциальный клиент'")
```

[image]

Comment: Everything used to work, recently, the result of the entire query appears in the first row in each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not specify the header rows so query just guess it

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1bk-Yp83zd6vnTrvZnVaGKHDuCJNTiOwEGEw5GDwHrOg"; "Покупатели!B2:O")};
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col6,Col,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14 
  where Col3 = 'Потенциальный клиент'"; 1)
```